Read mail instantly using graph API for automation process
I have created one web hook to read new mails and start process on that mails. Now sometimes this webhook doesn't trigger it instantaneously. It take some time around 10-30 minutes and then gets triggered. How can I resolve this issue ?
I am using azure function to process new mails.
I know this is not the best way to ask question but I didn't find anything else on my query so taking help from Stack overflow Developer community.
Thanks in advance.

There can be some latency, based on the resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#latency, but for mails, max. latency should be around 3 minutes

@user2250152 some times it also missing notification for new messages as well. We have to create new function which will trigger every 30 mins to check if any new messages are missed or not.
